# How to render inline element using beautiful soup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am converting  tag to confluence macro using bs4

input:

```html
<p>
<img src="path/to/file.jpg" />
</p>
```

expected output:

```html
<p>
    <ac:image ac:align="center" ac:layout="center">
        <ri:attachment ri:filename="file.jpg" ri:version-at-save="1" />
    </ac:image>
</p>
```

Here's the function that's being used to achieve it

```py
def transform_img_to_confluence(soup):
    def get_image_tag(image_name):
        return BeautifulSoup(textwrap.dedent('''
            <ac:image ac:align="center" ac:layout="center">
                <ri:attachment ri:filename="{}" ri:version-at-save="1" />
            </ac:image>
        ''').format(image_name), "html.parser")
        


    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
        path = img['src']
        image_name = os.path.basename(path)

        image_tag = get_image_tag(image_name)
        img.replace_with(image_tag)
```

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, "html.parser")
transform_img_to_confluence(soup)

print(soup.prettify())
```

When I inspect soup after calling this function, I'm expecting  tags to be replaced to the following  ( `ri:attachment` element as inline )

```html
<ac:image ac:align="center" ac:layout="center">
    <ri:attachment ri:filename="file.jpg" ri:version-at-save="1" />
</ac:image>
```

but unfortunately I'm getting this instead. ( `ri:attachment` with open and close tags )

```html
<ac:image ac:align="center" ac:layout="center">
    <ri:attachment ri:filename="file.jpg" ri:version-at-save="1">
    </ri:attachment>
</ac:image>
```

How to make sure I'm getting the desired inline element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem comes from the parser. in your case `lxml-xml` should do. here are some example outputs from available parsers

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a="""<a><b /></a>"""
print(BeautifulSoup(a, 'lxml'))
>>> <html><body><a><b></b></a></body></html>

print(BeautifulSoup(a, 'lxml-xml'))
>>> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>>> <a><b/></a>

print(BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser'))
>>> <a><b></b></a>

print(BeautifulSoup(a, 'html5lib'))
>>> <html><head></head><body><a><b></b></a></body></html>
```